# Dynamically update in stored procedure

Tags: database, oracle, stored-procedures

This is Dynamic select query SP, if the value is not null , it include in where clause otherwise not.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE GET_STORE(
       _storeId IN NUMBER DEFAULT NULL,
       _storename IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
       _return_Result OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
      )AS
      BEGIN
      OPEN _return_Result FOR
      SELECT S.*  FROM STORE  S 
      WHERE (NVL(_storeId,0) =0 OR S.STOREID=_storeId)
            AND (_storename IS NULL OR S.STORENAME=_storename);
 END RD_CITY;
```

how we can do same thing for update , means update those columns that are not null.

Comment: This procedure is very clever, but it has a tiny dsadvantage - it prevent's the optimiser from using any indices, and always does a full table scan, for each update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really want to know what row you are updating (the key), otherwise you will update the whole table. So you need a primary key on the table that is unique for each row (I added a column called storekey). Then you can use the nvl function to only update values that are not null:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE UPDATE_STORE(
       pstorekey IN NUMBER,
       pstoreid IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
       pstorename IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL
      )
AS
BEGIN

    update store
    set storeid = nvl(pstoreid,storeid),
    storename = nvl(pstorename,storename)
    where storekey = pstorekey;

    commit;

END update_store;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GET_STORE(
  _storeId       IN  STORE.STOREID%TYPE   DEFAULT NULL,
  _storename     IN  STORE.STORENAME%TYPE DEFAULT NULL,
  _return_Result OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
)
AS
BEGIN
  OPEN _return_Result FOR
    SELECT *
    FROM   STORE
    WHERE  ( _storeId   IS NULL OR STOREID=_storeId )
    AND    ( _storename IS NULL OR STORENAME=_storename );
END GET_STORE;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE UPDATE_STORE(
  _storeId       IN  STORE.STOREID%TYPE   DEFAULT NULL,
  _storename     IN  STORE.STORENAME%TYPE DEFAULT NULL,
  _othervalue    IN  STORE.OTHERVALUE%TYPE
)
AS
BEGIN
  UPDATE store
    SET   othervalue = _othervalue
    WHERE  ( _storeId   IS NULL OR STOREID=_storeId )
    AND    ( _storename IS NULL OR STORENAME=_storename );
END UPDATE_STORE;
/
```